Array on Python Processing 3.5.4
I'm building a radar. I have some problems with the lines that show where an object is located.

This is how it works now, but I want the different lines to have different values, so I need an array, I searched on internet but I couldn't figure out how to do it.
I'm using processing 3.5.4.
I coded it on this way but the array is wrote wrong,I know. How can I write it correctly?
I used a lot of c++, bot with python I'm on the beginning.
add_library('serial')

distance = array[360]

def setup():
    size(801, 801)  # Dimensioni della finestra
    global f
    f = createFont("Arial", 20)
    ser = Serial(this, "COM5", 9600)
    LF = 10
    ser.bufferUntil(LF)

def draw():
    global distance  # Dichiarazione della variabile distance come globale
    rectMode(CENTER)
    stroke(255)
    fill(0)
    rect(400, 400, 800, 800)
    ellipseMode(CENTER)
    ellipse(400, 400, 800, 800)
    ellipse(400, 400, 600, 600)
    ellipse(400, 400, 400, 400)
    ellipse(400, 400, 200, 200)
    line(400, 0, 400, 800)
    line(0, 400, 800, 400)
    line(400 - 400 * cos(0.785), 400 - 400 * sin(0.785), 400 + 400 * cos(0.785), 400 + 400 * sin(0.785))
    line(400 - 400 * cos(0.785), 400 + 400 * sin(0.785), 400 + 400 * cos(0.785), 400 - 400 * sin(0.785))
    textFont(f)
    fill(255)
    text("25cm", 440, 390)
    text("50cm", 540, 390)
    text("75cm", 640, 390)
    text("100cm", 730, 390)
    for i in range(360):
        stroke(0,255,0)
        line(400, 400,400+distance[i]*4*cos(radians(i)), 400+distance[i]*4*sin(radians(i)))
        stroke(255,0,0)
        line(400+distance[i]*4*cos(radians(i)), 400+distance[i]*4*sin(radians(i)),400+400*cos(radians(i)),400+400*sin(radians(i)))
        print(distance[i])  # Stampa la distanza attuale

def serialEvent(evt):
    x = 0
    global distance 
    inString = evt.readString().strip()  
    distance[x] =int(inString)
    x = x + 1
    if (x == 360):
        x = 0


What is add_library(); in Python you use import to load libraries.

What array library are you using? The standard array module isn't used the way you show, nor are numpy arrays.

I don't understand the serialEvent() function. It resets i to 0 every time it's called, so it always fills in distance[(0, 0)]. It seems like i should be a global variable that's initialized outside the function, so it increments every time you call the function.

if i == 359: should be if i == 360:

@Barmar On Processing i pressed the button libraries then add serial.  The programm automatically added the first line.

I'm not familiar with Processing. You tagged this as Python, but they're different languages.

@Barmar It can be confusing: there's the original Processing (java), p5.js and Processing.py (which uses Jython to for Python syntax/JVM interaction).

The following source code will run in Processing 3.5.4.  The more recent editor Processing 4.x no longer supports Python.  The most difficult part of this example is parsing the serial string input in order to convert to a float value. Serial data shows up in your app looking something like this: u'112\r\n and needs to be converted to 112.0 so it can be added to an array and used in your project.  The Arduino code that I used is appended to the source code.
add_library('serial')

distance = []
ser = Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600)
inStr = ""
x = 0
num = 0.0
i = 0

def setup():
    global ser
    size(801, 801)  # Dimensioni della finestra
    global f
    f = createFont("Arial", 20)
    printArray(Serial.list())
    LF = 10
    ser.bufferUntil(LF)

def draw():
    global distance  # Dichiarazione della variabile distance come globale
    global ser
    global inStr
    global x
    global num
    global i
    
    inStr = ser.readStringUntil(10)
    if (inStr != None):
        inStr = inStr.strip()
        inStr = inStr.lstrip("u")
        inStr = inStr.strip("'\uffd")
        inStr = inStr.rstrip("\\r\\n")
        inStr = inStr.strip(" ")
        if(inStr.isdigit()):
           num = float(inStr)
           print(num)
           distance.append(num)
           x = x + 1
           if (x > 359):
               x = 0

    stroke(255)
    fill(0)
    rect(400, 400, 800, 800)
    ellipseMode(CENTER)
    ellipse(400, 400, 800, 800)
    ellipse(400, 400, 600, 600)
    ellipse(400, 400, 400, 400)
    ellipse(400, 400, 200, 200)
    line(400, 0, 400, 800)
    line(0, 400, 800, 400)
    line(400 - 400 * cos(0.785), 400 - 400 * sin(0.785), 400 + 400 * cos(0.785), 400 + 400 * sin(0.785))
    line(400 - 400 * cos(0.785), 400 + 400 * sin(0.785), 400 + 400 * cos(0.785), 400 - 400 * sin(0.785))
    textFont(f)
    fill(255)
    text("25cm", 440, 390)
    text("50cm", 540, 390)
    text("75cm", 640, 390)
    text("100cm", 730, 390)

    for i in range(len(distance)):
        stroke(0,255,0)
        line(400, 400,400+distance[i]*4*cos(radians(i)), 400+distance[i]*4*sin(radians(i)))
        stroke(255,0,0)
        line(400+distance[i]*4*cos(radians(i)), 400+distance[i]*4*sin(radians(i)),400+400*cos(radians(i)),400+400*sin(radians(i)))
        print(distance[i])  # Stampa la distanza attuale


# **** Arduino code that was used ****

"""
byte outputValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    outputValue += 4;
    Serial.println(outputValue);
    delay(1);
  }
"""


Output:

